# How can i write Sum of natural numbers formula in JS code. i attempted this code but failed to understand what went wrong

Tags: javascript, variables, parameters, formula, jsfiddle

```js
    let sumOfSquareNum = (num) =>{
        let S =  (num(num + 1)(2*num + 1 )/6)
       
      alert (`The result of sum of 50 is ${S} where input is ${num}` )
      }
    sumOfSquareNum(5)
```

Comment: What are you expeting `num(num + 1)` to do?

Comment: `(num(num + 1)(2*num + 1 )/6)` -> `(num*(num + 1)*(2*num + 1 )/6)`?

Comment: Thanks :) @VLAZ .  problem rectified

Answer (score 1):

You need to insert `*` where it is implied otherwise you will get a `TypeError` since it is syntactically incorrect because of the missing operators.

```js
const sumOfSquareNum = (num) => {
  const S = (num * (num + 1) * (2 * num + 1) / 6)

  alert(`The result of sum of 50 is ${S} where input is ${num}`)
}
sumOfSquareNum(5);
```

Comment: OP's code is valid syntax. It throws a `TypeError` when `num(num + 1)` calls `num` as a function

Comment: Thanks :) @Nils Kähler. problem rectified